# Несколько веб-серверов: обслуживание PHP-сессии

Tags: php, apache, веб-сервер

Вопрос только относительно вебсервера. По поводу децентрализации, репликации бд я имею некоторе представление об уменьшении нагрузки.

Ситуация: На вебсервер приходит пользователь (много пользователей), делает что-то... и постепенно нагрузка повышается.

От пользователя приходит запрос к серверу, но так как сервер достиг максимальной нагрузки (при которой будет происходить ее распределение), то этот запрос будет переадресован на другую машину (другой сервер). НО после переадрасации зарпоса на другой комп., клиент (пользователь) получит другой идентификатор сессии.

*Сессия на первом сервере станет не актуальной*(**?**)

Как решается эта проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас нагрузка так велика, что для обслуживания посетителей требуется несколько серверов приложения, то хранить сессии штатно на диске крайне не разумно - вы слишком часто будете дергать жесткий диск - лучше поместить сессии в оперативную память. Обычно, в этом случае прибегают к хранению их в каком-нибудь NoSQL-хранилище, например, memcached, под который неплохо выделить отдельный сервер (но для начала можно разместить на одном из текущих серверов).

Для переноса сессий с диска в память, достаточно установить сервер memcached, расширение PHP и назначить сервер memcached в качестве обработка сессий в php.ini в секции [Session]

```
[Session]
...
session.save_handler = 'memcached'
session.save_path = 'mem00.domain.com:11211'
```

Если один memcached не будет справляться, то можно ввести несколько нод, расширение будет автоматически вычислять на какой из нод находится нужная в сессия текущего пользователя

```
[Session]
...
session.save_handler = 'memcached'
session.save_path = 'mem00.domain.com:11211, mem01.domain.com:11211'
```

Comment: у меня даже код сайта не дописан. Спрашиваю на будущее, чтобы более-менее правильно делать. Чтобы в будущем меньше проблем было.

Comment: вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541023/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть два варианта - либо вынести хранение сессии в отдельный слой (хороший вариант, описан в соседнем ответе), либо поставить на входе умный балансировщик (e.g. haproxy) и отсылать пользователей на конкретный сервер по значению той или иной куки (кука сама по себе не говорит, на какой сервер приземлится пользователь, она просто участвует в механизме расчета конечного сервера), чтобы сессия хранилась там. Второй вариант очень дешевый, но в то же время очень нестабильный (любое изменение кластера приведет к тому, что вся система "поедет"), поэтому применять его можно только на тот период, когда сервак уже не держит и надо добавить второй, а времени на перенос сессий пока нет. Ну и остается вариант с вертикальным масштабированием, которого вам скорее всего хватит на ближайших проектах.

По-хорошему сам PHPшный механизм сессий в нагруженных проектах использоваться не должен.

Comment: "По-хорошему сам PHPшный механизм сессий в нагруженных проектах использоваться не должен." - интрига :). Поищу, почитаю, попробую разобраться.