# Хранение файлов php-сессий в памяти (не в кеше!)

Tags: php, сессия, highload

Вопрос возник из ответов на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540987/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Я никогда и нигде не видел (наверное потому что не искал?) информации о хранении сессий прямо в памяти (не в кеше!).

О том что такое сессия, о том где данные сессии сохраняются рассказывать вам не нужно.

Ну так почему бы на сервере не создать РАМдиск такого размера чтобы туда влезли все возможные сессии? Например у меня размер файла сесии (примерно!) 100 байт.

[image: размер файла сесии]

Умножаем 100 байт на максимально возможное количество пользователей 100 * 4 294 967 295 = 4 294 967 295 000 байт (это если я не ошибаюсь) меньше полгигабайта(?). О рациональности использования ОП и про задержки при работе с ЖесткДиском - тут не говорим. (или говорим ;%)))

Пишем в /etc/fstab

```
tmpfs /ramsess tmpfs noatime,nodiratime,nodev,nosuid,size=512M 0 0
```

устанавливаем session.save_path и никаких обращений к диску!

**Если все так просто, то почему это никто(?) не использует?** И встречали ли вы в своей практике такой подход? В чем его опасность? Неудобство, невозможность (трудность) реализации?

ВАЖНО: Переменные сессии должны быть не сильно динамически изменяемые.

О том  что если будут вноситься изменения в код и возможна ситуация (изменения данных (добавление переменных) в сессии) нехватки места в рам диске для 4 МЛРД пользователей, не стоит говорить. Вопрос не об этом.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Используют, это нормально**, особенно когда все приложение убирается на одном сервере и есть избыток оперативной памяти. Однако это менее удобно, если у вас система вырастет и ее придется масштабировать. Пока она маленькая, у вас мало пользователей и в сессиях хранится мало информации. Однако, если система разрастется, вам будет сложно оперировать локальным жестким диском в памяти.

1) Диск расположен на одной ноде, если у вас 10 нод, как вы будете осуществлять доступ к сессиям? Даже если вы организуете обмен, у вас будет масса внутреннего трафика между нодами, и чем больше вы их вводите, тем трафик будет выше, вплоть до того, что вы им забьете канал. Поэтому лучше сразу разрабатывать систему с прицелом на масштабируемость.

2) Допустим размер вырос на столько, что у вас данные не убираются на одном сервере, не хватает памяти - как вы будете масштабировать эту систему? Как быстро распространить этот диск на два сервера? С NoSQL-сервером проблем нет - они кластеризуются из коробки, а как тут поступить? Писать собственный сервер?

Когда система большая, не хочется уже оригинальных решений, хочется надежных, так как различных проблем очень много и хочется хотя бы часть исключить как класс. Диск в оперативной памяти - это хорошее бюджетное решение, в случае, если вы не планируете разрастаться за пределы одного сервера. Если такая вероятность есть - лучше сразу вводить слои приложения (база данных, nosql, приложение, фронт-сервера, сервера статики, кэш, очереди заданий и т.п.) и назначать им поддомены - будет проще потом систему перевести на использование нескольких серверов.

Если система не растет, если вы можете предсказывать нагрузку на годы вперед, диск в оперативной памяти под сессии - вполне нормальное решение.

Comment: Если вы (и не только вы) говорите что такой подход не очень пригоден - то так оно и есть. У вас больше опыта. НО по поводу "как организовать доступ к этому рам диску для других машин" у меня придумалась бешеная идея.  Можно же рассшарить этот диск другим серверам через Самбу или nfs (или копировать rsync`ом) - но я повторбюсь - это всегго лишь бешеная мысль. Если опытный дед сказал что лучше NoSQL, значит буду копать в сторону NoSQL.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, если хотите попробуйте - так делают. Однако, когда приложение будет расти, вы будете от этого диска избавляться - это гораздо менее удобно, чем поддомен с каким-нибудь memcached. Случись чего-то, воткнули новый сервер на этот подомен - система продолжила работать. А если что-то случится с сервером, где у вас расшарен диск, вам придется вывести из боя эту ноду вместе со всеми сервисами и вставить такую же с таким же разделом. Подготовить сервер с одним memcached менее сложно, чем с разделом и приложением. Да и вообще, проще компоненты - тем вам проще будет с ними работать.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, просто когда у вас один сервер и один жесткий диск, вероятность его выхода из строя - один раз в четыре года. Если у вас 10 000 жестких дисков они выходят из строя по 3-4 штуки в день. Поверьте в таких условиях вам не захочется иметь сложно-устроенные ноды, чем проще они будут устроены, чем проще автоматизировать их установку - тем все дешевле и быстрее. Это не значит, что не надо пробовать раздел в оперативной памяти - это хороший опыт. Просто возможно не стоит закладывать это в продакшен.

Comment: " Подготовить сервер с одним memcached сложнее, чем с разделом и приложением. " не совсем понял. Ну а все остальное, кажись, понятно.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, пока приложение маленькое, пока сервер один - вам проще все делать руками, поставить операционную систему, установить и настроить ПО - это приятно и полезно, навыки не забываются. Когда серверов много, руками все делать уже опасно - можно забыть что-то поставить, рутина утомляет - появляются ошибки. Поэтому ставят какой-нибудь автоматической системой puppet, chef, ansible, salt - их нужно грубо говоря программировать. Чем проще нода, чем ноды меньше отличаются друг от друга - тем проще код, тем меньше ошибок и проблем, тем больше у вас времени на развитие продукта.

Comment: Можно сервер с redis использовать как вариант за место memcached но у redis есть свои минусы такие как персистетность (в момент сохранения данных на диск не доступен) промежуток маленький но неприятный при большой нагрузке. Но при грамотной настройки это плюс.

Comment: 2cheops: это я понял, НО может вы хотели написать "Подготовить сервер с одним memcached ПРОЩЕ, чем с разделом и приложением." ИЛИ вы все верно написали, и имели в виду то, что сложнее подготовить !сервер с одним memcached!  в случае сбоя сервера с рамдиском? - вот что именнео до меня не дошло.